# Building HPL errors

Tags: build, mpi, openmpi, hpc, blas

I have been trying to build HPL with no success. I have installed Open MPI and it is running correctly. I also have the BLAS library.
But when I try to build I get some errors related to openmpi, I think. For example, I found that "opal_install_dirs" is a symbol from libopen-pal. But I don't know where these undefined references come from so I don't know what to do to fix it.

```
fcoll_dynamic_file_write_all.c:(.text+0x20f0): undefined reference to `opal_output'
fcoll_dynamic_file_write_all.c:(.text+0x2122): undefined reference to `opal_output'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(fcoll_dynamic_file_write_all.o):fcoll_dynamic_file_write_all.c:(.text+0x216e): more undefined references to `opal_output' follow
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(pinfo_create.o): In function `PMPI_Info_create':
pinfo_create.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `opal_class_initialize'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(ppack_external.o): In function `PMPI_Pack_external':
ppack_external.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_t_class'
ppack_external.c:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_prepare_for_send'
ppack_external.c:(.text+0x1ed): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_pack'
ppack_external.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `opal_class_initialize'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(ppack_external_size.o): In function `PMPI_Pack_external_size':
ppack_external_size.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_t_class'
ppack_external_size.c:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_prepare_for_recv'
ppack_external_size.c:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `opal_class_initialize'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(punpack_external.o): In function `PMPI_Unpack_external':
punpack_external.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_t_class'
punpack_external.c:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_prepare_for_recv'
punpack_external.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `opal_convertor_unpack'
punpack_external.c:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `opal_class_initialize'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(pstatus_set_elements_x.o): In function `PMPI_Status_set_elements_x':
pstatus_set_elements_x.c:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `opal_datatype_set_element_count'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(libdebuggers_la-ompi_debuggers.o): In function `check':
/home/snc/workspace/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers/ompi_debuggers.c:146: undefined reference to `opal_argv_append_nosize'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(libdebuggers_la-ompi_debuggers.o): In function `ompi_debugger_setup_dlls':
/home/snc/workspace/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers/ompi_debuggers.c:171: undefined reference to `opal_install_dirs'
/home/snc/workspace/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers/ompi_debuggers.c:172: undefined reference to `mca_base_var_register'
/home/snc/workspace/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers/ompi_debuggers.c:181: undefined reference to `opal_argv_split'
/home/snc/workspace/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers/ompi_debuggers.c:186: undefined reference to `opal_argv_free'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(osc_rdma_frag.o):(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `opal_free_list_item_t_class'
/usr/local/lib/libmpi.a(vprotocol_pessimist_event.o):(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `opal_list_item_t_class'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'dexe.grd' failed
make[2]: *** [dexe.grd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mpiuser/cloud/hpl/testing/ptest/Linux_Intel64'
Make.top:64: recipe for target 'build_tst' failed
make[1]: *** [build_tst] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mpiuser/cloud/hpl'
Makefile:72: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

This is only the end part of the output of make.

On the configuration file for HPL I have:

```
MPdir        = /usr/local
MPinc        = $(MPdir)/include
MPlib        = $(MPdir)/lib/libmpi.a
...
LAdir        = /usr/lib/libblas
ifndef  LAinc
LAinc        = 
endif
ifndef  LAlib
LAlib        = $libblas.a
endif
...
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Compilers / linkers - Optimization flags ---------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
CC       = mpicc
CCNOOPT  = $(HPL_DEFS)

CCFLAGS  = $(HPL_DEFS) -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops -fopenmp
#
# On some platforms,  it is necessary  to use the Fortran linker to find
# the Fortran internals used in the BLAS library.
#
LINKER       = $(CC)
LINKFLAGS    = $(CCFLAGS)  
#
ARCHIVER     = ar
ARFLAGS      = r
RANLIB       = echo
```

I tried different options there, from information that I found on several posts and forums, and I got over some other previous errors, but I can't find anything to fix this one. Can someone see what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The `mpicc` compiler wrapper will pass the correct MPI include and library paths to the underlying compiler automatically. Explicitly setting `MPinc` and `MPlib` is a recipe for disaster!

Comment: I tried that too, but I still had the problem. Why is it set in every sample configuration I've seen then?

Comment: Because not every MPI implementation provides such compiler wrappers and with some the library must be linked in explicitly using the regular compiler and linker. With Open MPI, Intel MPI, MPICH, MVAPICH, and a multitude of other modern libraries, you should set both `MPinc` and `MPlib` to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply using libmpi.so instead of libmpi.a, but I am not sure what the difference is. Most of the examples of configuration I saw before used the *.a library, except for one that used libmpi.so.

Comment: `mpicc` already passes all the necessary libraries to the compiler and the linker. Use `mpicc --showme` to see for yourself. Open MPI is split into multiple components (OpenRTE, OPAL, MPI interface, etc.) and links them all dynamically by default. `libmpi.a` is the static MPI interface. It depends on the static versions of the other components and those are not provided in your case, hence the unresolved external symbol errors (dynamic and static symbols cannot be mixed). The proper solution is to set `MPinc` and `MPlib` to empty strings and let `mpicc` take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the question by setting MPinc and MPlib to empty Strings

Comment: A more detailed explanation would make this a more helpful answer.